# Custom slide show

Tags: plugin, wordpress

I have development custome slideshow.
Backend it work normally **insert . update delete and templates of this slide**  .
How can I show this slide in home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download this module and see how it work: https://github.com/magiccart/magento-2-banner-slider